# how to remove record permanantely from mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have been working on a spring boot and react project with MySQL as my main DB when ever I perform DELETE operation on **ID = 1** from the client or react it deletes the record fields like the firstName, lastName, email but the ID is still there so when I POST new record instead of assigning the deleted id it increments by 1 **(ID = 2)** I don't know why is this happening? can anyone help thanks

Comment: This is just the behavior of the auto increment `ID` column and is nothing to worry about.  What is wrong with `ID = 2` for a new record?

Comment: Right.  Autoincrement doesn't reuse numbers that get released.  It increments every time you insert a record, and never decrements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nothing but  i just wanted nice ordered data , thanks sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of AutoIncrement. AutoIncrement never uses deleted id again because it could be a bad idea in many cases. For instance, You have **millions of records** and you **delete something from the beginning**, the database has to **shift all of the data  1 id backward** which is not a good idea.

Comment: thanks brother the question was answered earlier in the comment section but i will accept this as answer so the question will be closed thanks again